# Not able to access uploaded files in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, file-upload, ng-file-upload

Latest code which helps me in solving my problem

```js
    $scope.uploadedFiles = [];

    $scope.upload = function(files) {
        $scope.uploadedFiles = files;
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            if (file && !file.$error) {
                if($scope.uploadedFiles.indexOf(file) == -1) {
                  $scope.uploadedFiles.push(file);
                }
                file.upload = Upload.upload({
                  url: 'uploader',
                  file: file,
                  userId: $scope.user._id
                });

                file.upload.then(function (response) {
                  $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data.id;
                  });
                }, function (response) {
                  if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                });

                file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
                  file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                });
          }   
        });
        console.log($scope.uploadedFiles);

    }

    $scope.removeUploadedFile = function(files, idx) {
      files.splice(idx, 1);
      console.log($scope.uploadedFiles);
      $scope.uploadedFiles = files;
      console.log($scope.uploadedFiles);
    }
```

```html
         .form-group
          .btn.btn-default.btn-file
           i.fa.fa-paperclip
           |  Attach Files
           input(type='file', ngf-select='upload($files)',accept="text/plain, image/*", ng-model="files", ngf-multiple="true", ngf-max-size='10000000', ngf-keep="true", ngf-keep-distinct="true")
          p.help-block Max. 1MB
          br
          ul#files(ng-repeat="f in files", style='list-style-type: none; padding:0; margin:0;')
           li
            div
             {{f.name}}
             .pull-right
              {{f.size | bytes}} &nbsp; #[i.fa.fa-close(ng-click="removeUploadedFile(files, $index)")]
            div.progress(ng-show="f.progress >= 0")
             div(style="width:{{f.progress}}%", ng-bind="f.progress + '%'")
```

I'm using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage) for handling of file uploads. Everything is working fine except that I'm not able to access **files** in my controller.

Here is my controller code:

```
$scope.upload = function(files) {
    uploadedFiles = files;
    console.log($scope.files);
    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        if (file && !file.$error) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
              url: 'uploader',
              file: file,
              userId: $scope.user._id
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
              $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data.id;
              });
            }, function (response) {
              if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
              file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
      }   
    });

    console.log(uploadedFiles);
}

$scope.removeUploadedFile = function(files, idx) {
  console.log(files);
  files.splice(idx, 1);
  uploadedFiles = files;
}
```

And my html code:

```
                                .form-group
                                    .btn.btn-default.btn-file
                                        i.fa.fa-paperclip
                                        |  Attach Files
                                        input(type='file', name='attachment', ngf-select='upload($files)',accept="text/plain, image/*", ng-model="files", ngf-multiple="true", ngf-max-size='10000000', ngf-keep="true", ngf-keep-distinct="true")
                                    p.help-block Max. 1MB
                                    br
                                    //- ul(ng-repeat='file in uploadedFiles', style='list-style-type: none; padding:0; margin:0;')
                                    ul#files(ng-repeat='f in files', style='list-style-type: none; padding:0; margin:0;')
                                        li
                                            div
                                                {{f.name}}
                                                .pull-right
                                                    {{f.size | bytes}} &nbsp; #[i.fa.fa-close(ng-click="removeUploadedFile(files, $index)")]
                                            div.progress(ng-show="f.progress >= 0")
                                                div(style="width:{{f.progress}}%", ng-bind="f.progress + '%'")
```

If I print `$scope.files`, it prints nothing.

Any pointers where am I doing wrong will be appreciated.

**Update:**

Why do I need to access `$scope.files` ? File upload functionalty is working fine but I need to pass uploaded files id to my backend systems for saving that id in my db. Now to do that I need some `$scope` variable which contains updated list of files. Since I'm allowing the user to delete the uploaded file, I need some `$scope` variable to be updated with the latest list of valid uploaded files. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: It seems about right, can you try with $scope.$watch('files',...) instead of calling upload function from ngf-select.

Comment: If you could create a jsfiddle I could give you feedback faster.

Comment: @danial: I'll be sharing the JSFiddle soon. Meanwhile, can you just show me in one of your sample fiddles available on github page to show how can I access $scope.files variable in some other function. Thanks

Comment: $scope.files is never set, so it is normal if it prints nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some issues with ngf-keep which is fixed in version 7.0.12.
Your original post should work now or you can follow this: https://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/e7x1xs4a/

```
<button ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" ngf-keep="true" multiple>Select Files</button>

$scope.uploadFiles = function(files) {
    $scope.files = files;
    console.log(files);
    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        if (file && !file.$error) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
              url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
              file: file
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {"success"
            }, function (response) {"error"});

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {"progress"});
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some issue when not using ng-model. I tried removing ng-model field and it started giving me error https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/936

Comment: Also, as a work around to my problem, I'm using ng-model="files". And to support my removal case, I'm passing files as a param in the function and inside controller I have a separate field which keeps updated files list

Comment: My current version is 5.0.9. How come I have older version. I have recently installed the package using bower. Is the latest version not yet pushed in the repo ?

Comment: The issue is fixed in the latest. If you go to https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload you would see the latest npm version (and bower) is 7.0.12

Comment: You can do a bower update or change the version to 7.0.12 manually in your bower.json

Answer (score 0):

I guess ng-file-upload updates the scope value after calling ngf-select function.

Althought I don't understand why you want to access `$scope.files` in your updload function even though you can access the same value via function parameter. 
If you insist to use `$scope.files`, you could wrap your logic by $timeout.

The sample code is like below.

```
$scope.upload = function(){
    console.log('Outside $timeout :', $scope.files);
    $timeout(function(){
        console.log('Inside $timeout :', $scope.files);
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/1m6fn6re/33/)

### My suggestion:

1. When you need to access `files` in ngf-select function, I recommend to use simply the function parameter.
2. When you want to access `files` in other function, you can simply access `$scope.files`.

Comment: Is it something like we can access $scope.files only inside $timeout ? Please refer to my update for the use case why I need to access this

Comment: How can I access $scope.files variable in some other function ?

Comment: You can access $scope.files simply in other function. You need to wrap by  $timeout **ONLY** in ngf-select function. Check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/1m6fn6re/33/) I updated.

Comment: But in my case $scope.files is not showing proper values. You can see my controller code if I print $scope.files then it prints undefined. Any idea what can be the possible reason ?

Comment: "I guess ng-file-upload updates the scope value after calling ngf-select function." this is fixed at version 7.0.12

Answer (score 0):

**edited**:

If you want to update files every time you add a new file, you need to set `$scope.files` outside the function scope and push new file in `$scope.files` array `$scope.files.push(file);` :

```
$scope.files = [];

function uploadFiles(files) {
    angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
        $scope.files.push(file);

        if (file && !file.$error) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
              url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
              file: file
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
              $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
              });
            }, function (response) {
              if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
              file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                       evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Few doubts: You have removed ng-model="files" from the html file. Also, you are doing $scope.files = files; but my use case keeps previously added files. Doing this assignment will override the previously added files. Also, why are we removing ng-model from html ? My use case also allows the user to delete added files. Refer to my jade code.$scope.removeUploadedFile How can I ensure that $scope.files is always consistent ?

Comment: I'm not doing anything, I copy the jsfiddle link from the doc. If you want to do `ng-repeat='f in files'` you have to do somewhere something like `$scope.files = files;` If you want to iterate over uploadedFiles, you have to do `$scope.uploadedFiles = files;` and `ng-repeat='f in uploadedFiles'` . If you want to update instead of replace when you upload again, you have to concat two files arrays